# Limit user to perform an action a certain number of times in a day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spam

I am using Rails 3.1.0 with Devise 2.1.0. I would like to limit the number of times a user can perform an action in a day. The main purpose of this limitation is to prevent spam.

I see many questions similar to this one but was wondering if there is a specific way to accomplish what I am trying to do through Devise.

For the actions that create model instances, the number of times an action has been performed in a day is easy to keep track of. However, at least one action that I would like to restrict does not create a model instance, so I'm not sure what to do about it.

I was also wondering if this is a legitimate/effective way of preventing spam (in addition to requiring users to register and sign in to perform the actions).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find these sorts of systems to be over-complications. Unless spam is an existing, provable problem I'm not sure adding in a system that's likely to be rather extensive is a good use of time and energy.

Alternatives to this would be requiring registration through a third-party service (say Facebook) and using either [captchas](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/) or exciting and new [negative captchas](https://github.com/subwindow/negative-captcha).

That said, if you want to do this, I think the best place to keep track of it would be in an ephemeral data store. Redis would be really good for this since you can use queues. In the actions that you want to restrict, add a timestamp to the queue, and before you allow the user to perform said action, check the number of elements in the queue, purging ones that are too old while you do so.

That's sort of pseudo-codey, but should at least help you get started.